# Windows 11 install failed now I can't install again

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I am trying to update to Windows 11, but for some reason it is saying that I am up to date (Windows version 10).

I downloaded and installed it from Windows Update a few weeks ago, however, the install didn't work that time. So I have been trying again and again for the past few weeks and still cant get it to download and install a second time.

[image: Update image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to update to Windows 11, but for some reason it is saying
> that I am up to date (Windows version 10).

The Windows 11 Rollout is a slow and steady pace. You may wish to just wait until the update starts itself.

Otherwise, please see this article below:

[Force Windows 11 to start the update](https://www.howtogeek.com/767274/how-to-force-the-windows-11-update-and-upgrade-immediately/https://)

.

> How to Force the Windows 11 Upgrade Right Now If you want Windows 11
> right now, the fastest way to get it is with Microsoft’s Windows 11
> Installation Assistant.
>
> To start installing Windows 11, visit Microsoft’s Download Windows 11
> website. Click the “Download Now” button under the Windows 11
> Installation Assistant heading.
>
> Run the downloaded “Windows11InstallationAssistant.exe” file. It will
> check to see if your computer is compatible with Windows 11 in its
> current state. If your computer meets the requirements, it will offer
> to install Windows 11. Accept the license agreement and, after a more
> few clicks, the tool will begin installing Windows 11 on your PC.

Comment: I already waited to install the first time, do I have to wait again for another chance to try a second time?

Comment: If you are not in a rush, wait until it asks again. Otherwise, look through the article I posted

Comment: Okay thanks, I just wasn't sure if I broke something and it wouldn't let me update again (because something is broken), or if I just need to wait for it to ask me again. I guess I will just wait for it to ask me again.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDhNP.png) explains how you manually kick off the update. If that does not work, download the [Windows 11 Installation Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11), which will upgrade your installation to Windows 11.